# How can I extend/expand ItemAdd to work with more than 16 mails?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I have developed an Outlook add-in and I am using ItemAdd every time a new item comes to inbox. It works fine, but when I open Outlook after some hours/days it was closed, it does not work.

I searched on web and found that ItemAdd supports max 16 items. In some cases I may have 200+ items. How can I expand this number??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 items limit is a red herring - your problem is that your code is not running when the items are added. The events won't fire when Outlook starts up - for all it knows, the items were there for ages. You need to process "new" items on your own (unread items, items not in your list, etc.).

Most importantly, you should not be using events for any kind of synchronization - they are designed to be used for the UI purposes.

Comment: It may be a good approach to get all unreaded items and work on them? For instance, scan inbox every x minutes and move/delete etc them? This can cause any speed problems?

Comment: Yes, you can process all unread items on startup (assuming the user did not mark them as read from, for example, mobile Outlook). It is better to persist the creation time of the last item you processed and use a query on CreationTime when calling Items.Find / FindNext. Items.ItemAdd event can serve as a hint that you need to run your sync code now rather than later.

Comment: Thank you! Promise to accept your initial answer if I make it work on next days! :)